# jQuery Accordion Last section to diplay by defautl?

Tags: jquery, accordion

How can i make last section as active in accordion by default?

```
 $("#accordion").accordion("active", last)
```

as I will have a Dynamic set of sections in the accordion.

By default i wan the last section to be active

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `":last"` as the active selector. Pick ONE of these options depending on your style and preferences:

```
$("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", ":last"); // this one
$("#accordion").accordion({"active" : ":last"}); // OR this one; not both
```

[edited: it seems like you also need to pass "option" or use an options map]

Answer (score 6):

The zero-based index of the panel that is active (open). A negative value selects panels going backward from the last panel.

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
  active: -1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active", -1 ); works fine.